# Beez 3 Logo size

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm trying to change the size of the logo in beez3 on this website: https://jurahaus-verein.de/ to a smaller logo but so far didn't succeed with either of the following:
- saving it in a smaller size and uploading it
- changing the minimum size in personal.css as follows:

```
.logoheader {
background: url(../images/personal/personal2.png) no-repeat right
    bottom #0C1A3E;
color: #FFFFFF;
min-height: 175px;}
```

(deleting cookies and cash also didn't work). Is there any hint, how to make the logo smaller?

Comment: Are you referring to the actual logo or the banner?

Comment: The actual logo. The answer from user3774771 does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to change not logotype, but head background image (houses, road etc.)
Your logo is

```
<img src="/images/logo_mit_Anschrift_Rotkreuzgassetransp_kulturerbe.png" alt="">
```

and it styling in position.css file (class - #logo img on line 283). Add width to style to change the size of logo (do not forget the height: auto).

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Also thanks for the hint with the header size. That all helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try css `background-size` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size))

You can set it to something like `background-size:cover;` to have it size automatically.

or a percentage of the image size: `background-size:80%;`

or a set pixel width: `background-size:600px;`